# UIPanGestureRecognizer not calling End state

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uipangesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewlayout

using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` we are moving the cells in the `UICollectionView`

When we started dragging `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` is called. but when we still holds the dragging cell and presses the Home  Button in ipad, the  `UIPanGestureRecognizer` not calling `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`, not even calling gesture method

`- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;`

When i opened my app from background the cell is at the same place in the view but am not able to perform any actions on it. this is because of `UIPanGestureRecognizer` not calling the gestureStates.

How to end my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` when user presses the home button.

Comment: Did you try to log anything in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` condition?

Comment: yes i tried, its not calling even handlePanGesture: method

Comment: Can you please add the code for the gesture?

Comment: `- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer { 
switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: { //doing somthing here}} break;
case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            //calling method
        }
default: {
        } break;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

        [self.window setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }



    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

        [self.window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
```

Comment: touches are working fine.  am able perform other actions in the view like button press. But that cell is still in the that place and not in  the collectionview list

Comment: Even i reloaded the collectionview but that cell is at the same place and not added to the collectioview